Поиск количества вхождений элементов в отсортированном массиве для множества запросов
Условие:
Дан отсортированный целочисленный массив, содержащий повторяющиеся элементы и состоящий из n элементов.
Необходимо для каждого из m запросов найти, какое количество раз в данном массиве встречается заданное значение k.
Входные данные:
В первой строке входного файла дано значение n(1<=n<=100000) - количество элементов массива
Во второй строке входного файла дан сам массив.
В третьей строке входного файла дано значение m(1<=m<=100000) – количество запросов.
В каждой из следующих m строк дано единственное число – значение k (для каждого запроса значение k может быть как различно, так и одинаково).
Выходные данные:
Для каждого запроса в выходной файл должно быть выведено единственное значение - количество вхождений числа k в массив, если элемента k в массиве нет, то необходимо вывести - «Not found».
Значение для каждого нового запроса должно быть выведено в отдельной строке.
Ограничения:
Время — 1000 ms
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, x;
    cin >> n;
    int mas[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> mas[i];
    string s;
    cin >> x;

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        int ch = 0;
        int t; cin >> t;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (mas[j] == t) ch++;
        }
        if (ch != 0)
        {
            s += to_string(ch);
            s.append(" ");
        }
        else s.append("N ");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size(s); i++)
    {
        if (s[i] != 'N')
        {
            while (s[i] != ' ')
            {
                cout << s[i];
                i++;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Not found" << endl;
            i++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


Где, например, описание, что должна делать программа? Постановка задачи? Оптимизация любого кода начинается с оптимизации алгоритма...

Есть ли ограничения на сами значения? И, кстати, есть ли URL задачи с проверяющей системой?

@Harry, sort и equal_range?

@StanislavVolodarskiy Или map, например... В любом случае имеем O((n+m) log n) Но вдруг там значения ограничены, скажем, 10000? :)

@Harry, насчет ограничений кстати не знаю, мб стоит попробовать не int a long использовать, хотя сомневаюсь что это поможет.(не помогло)

Все-таки URL есть? Ну, чтоб попробовать и vq вариант, и вариант @StanislavVolodarskiy?

@Harry, увы, но URL нет(

@Harry, unordered_map уберёт логарифм из сложности.

Массив из k надо  отсортировать и сделать все за один проход по обеим массивам (проход по сути аналогичен слиянию массивов в сортировке слиянием)

@avp Меры по восстановлению порядка чисел в ответе потребуют второй сортировки второго массива :)

@Harry "Меры по ... потребуют второй сортировки ..." - нет, если сохранить первоначальный индекс вместе с каждым k.

@rotabor Именно этот способ я и имел в виду. И как вы его потом будете без сортировки искать? Сканить весь массив кучу раз?

@Harry за один проход элементы расставляются по новому массиву с использованием сохранённого индекса.

@rotabor Что-то я тупой к вечеру... Есть массив k, числа в беспорядке, грубо говоря. Нам надо их отсортировать - значит, нужен массив индексов этих чисел, так? Но чтоб потом быстро вывести ответ, нужно иметь индексы в отсортированном порядке? Или что вы имеете в виду?

@Harry for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) newk[sortedk[i].index] = sortedk[i].value

Сосчитать значения в counts, отвечать на запросы:
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<int, int> counts;

    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int v;
        std::cin >> v;
        counts[v] += 1;
    }

    int m;
    std::cin >> m;
    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
        int v;
        std::cin >> v;
        auto it = counts.find(v);
        if (it == counts.end()) {
            std::cout << "Not found\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << it->second << '\n';
        }
    }
}

Я упустил что значения на входе упорядочены. Тогда можно решить задачу по-другому:
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a;

    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int v;
        std::cin >> v;
        a.push_back(v);
    }

    int m;
    std::cin >> m;
    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
        int v;
        std::cin >> v;
        auto range = std::equal_range(a.begin(), a.end(), v);
        auto c = range.second - range.first;
        if (c == 0) {
            std::cout << "Not found\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << c << '\n';
        }
    }
}


Сомневаюсь я, что авторы задачи в самом деле хотели загнать отсортированный (по условию задачи) массив в хэш-таблицу. (но выглядит элегантно и очевидно, что работает за O(n + m))

@avp Забавно, слово "отсортированный" я как-то в условии пропустил.

Можно срастить идеи с мапой и с вектором. Исходный вектор хранить не "как есть", а вектор пар: <число, количество>

Вариант с хеш-таблицей, как в ответе выше - правильное и адекватное решение, которое работает даже не в отсортированном случае. Кроме того, быстрее никак не получится.
Однако, если по какой-то причине нужно решить без хеш-таблицы, можно делать это бинарным поиском поиском. Ищем самое левое и самое правое вхождение нужного элемента (происходит это за O(2log(n)) = O(log(n)), т.к. массив отсортирован). Итоговая временная сложность будет O(m*log(n)).

std::equal_range.

Мне показалось, человеку интересно, как это работает алгоритмически. Собственно, std::equal_range работает через бинарный поиск.

Хэш таблицы, или словари, ещё та засада. Накладные расходы на вычисление хэша немаленькие. И инициализировать нужно правильно. Поэтому есть варианты.
